# Creating an API namespaced controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I'm trying to test my namespaced controller and not having much luck. I have the following route setup:

```
namespace :api do
  get 'organization/:id/questions/:number', controller: 'questions', action: 'index', as: 'organization_questions'
end
```

which produces the following route:

```
api_organization_questions GET    /api/organization/:id/questions/:number(.:format)      {:controller=>"api/questions", :action=>"index"}
```

that route works, and I'm able to successfully make a request to it with the following url: http://localhost:3000/api/organization/1/questions/1234567890

However when I try to make a `get` request to it in my unit test I get the following error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"api/questions", :action=>"/api/organization/1/questions/1234567890"}

my get request looks like this:

```
get api_organization_questions_path(@organization.id, '1234567890')
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong!?

Comment: @juwiley that's the second snippet of code in the question: `api_organization_questions GET    /api/organization/:id/questions/:number(.:format)      {:controller=>"api/questions", :action=>"index"}`

Comment: Ahhh, sorry.  Compare test.log and development.log?  Params different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using for testing ? RSpec? The first parameter for the get method is the action. The code below should make the request you want:

```
describe Api::QuestionsController do
  it "should do something" do
    get :index, :id => @organization.id, :number => '1234567890'
  end
end
```